# Write and read JSON structure

Tags: angular, typescript

In in angular 10 application, I use an external conf file.

Load config file prior to app creation

In my config.json

```
{
  "oauth": {
    "clientId": "d1851226-abe8-4da6-8332-af8700e0d999",
    "redirectUri": "https://localhost:4200/find",
    "authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/4fc25658-72c2-42bf-913c-cb9ae315a689"
   }
}
```

In my app.module.ts

```
import { MsalInterceptorConfig } from './lib/msal/msal.interceptor.config';
import { MsalBroadcastService, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor, MsalService, MSAL_INSTANCE } from './lib/msal';
import { MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG } from './lib/msal/constants';
import { MsalGuardConfiguration } from './lib/msal/msal.guard.config';


function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
    return new PublicClientApplication({

        auth: {

           clientId: configService.getMSALConfiguration().clientId, 
           redirectUri: configService.getMSALConfiguration().redirectUri, 
           authority: configService.getMSALConfiguration().authority, 
           postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
        }
    });

}

function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfig {
    const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
    protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']);
    protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:8080/v2/**', ['openid' ]);
    protectedResourceMap.set('http://localhost:8081/v2/**', ['openid' ]);

    return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
       protectedResourceMap,
    };

}

@NgModule({

    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        FormValidationHintComponent
    ],

    imports: [

        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FontAwesomeModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        DataTablesModule,
        ModalModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot({
        preventDuplicates: true
        }),

        TranslateModule.forRoot({

        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: WebpackTranslateLoader
        },
        defaultLanguage: 'en'
        })
    ],

    providers: [

    DatePipe,
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
        multi: true
    },

    {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeApp,
            multi: true,
            deps: [HttpBackend, ConfigurationService]
    },

    {

        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: MsalInterceptor,
        multi: true
    },

    {
        provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
        useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },

    {
        provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,

        useValue: {
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup
        } as MsalGuardConfiguration
    },

    {
        provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
        useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },

    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

My configuration.ts

```
export interface Configuration {

    'oauth': {
        'clientId': string;
        'redirectUri': string;
        'authority': string;
    
    };
}
```

I would like to removed fixed value in my MsalInterceptorConfig  method and read it

How to add theses information in my JSON file and what modification I need to do in my configuration interface?

I tried

```
export interface Configuration {    
    'oauth': {
        'clientId': string;
        'redirectUri': string;
        'authority': string;
        'protectedResourceMap' : string;
    };
}


function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(configService: ConfigurationService): MsalInterceptorConfig {
    const protectedResourceMap = configService.getMSALConfiguration().protectedResourceMap;
    return {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
       protectedResourceMap,
    };

}
```

but I get: glob pattern string required

Comment: It is really unclear what you are trying to do. Perhaps an example of what this config file looks like, along with what value you are wanting to use, and where you are wanting to use it would help. Have you looked into using the standard environment.ts configuration? Does your configuration file change at run time, or is it part of your build process?

Comment: i add more information, should be clearer